# How to resolve custom list view while scrolling checking condition not working properly

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, scroll

I want to display items in list view with four attributes: id, name, marks, and date. Its working fine but when I scroll the listview and select the 1st item, it also selects the 16th item and sometimes the app crashes. I searched a lot but can't understand what's the problem.

```
       //Adapter class
    public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
        private Activity activity;
        int id;
        ArrayList<Item> items;
        public Adapter(Activity context, int resource, ArrayList<Item> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            this.activity=context;
            this.id=resource;
            this.items=objects;
        }

            @Override
                public int getViewTypeCount() {
                    return getCount();
                }

                @Override
                public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                    return position;
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(id, null);
                    }
                    Item item = items.get(position);
                    TextView tv_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
                    TextView tv_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
                    TextView tv_marks = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_marks);
                    TextView tv_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);

                    tv_id.setText(item.getId());
                    tv_name.setText(item.getName());
                    tv_marks.setText(item.getMarks());
                    tv_date.setText(item.getDat());

                    return convertView;
                } 
//item class-----------
public class Item {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String marks;
    private String dat;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(String marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public String getDat() {
        return dat;
    }

    public void setDat(String dat) {
        this.dat = dat;
    }
}


        // List view Class 

        public class List_Viwer extends AppCompatActivity {


            Context ctx = this;
            ListView listView;
            Adapter adapter;
            CheckBox checkBox;
                DatabaseHelper myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
                ArrayList<Item> arrayList=new ArrayList<Item>();

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list__viwer);

                    //checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllData();
                    if(cursor!= null) {
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                            do{
                                Item item = new Item();
                                item.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                                item.setName(cursor.getString(1));// gets id fromm database
                                item.setSurname(cursor.getString(2));  //gets title from database
                                item.setMarks(cursor.getString(3));
                                item.setDat(cursor.getString(4));// gets content / body from database
                                arrayList.add(item);
                            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        }
                        adapter = new Adapter(this, R.layout.custom_list_item, arrayList);
                        listView  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }

                    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            TextView temp_txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
                            String tempID = temp_txt.getText().toString();
                            // Toast.makeText(ctx, ID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(ctx, View_Person.class);
                            i.putExtra("ID", tempID);
                            ctx.startActivity(i);
                        }
                    });

                    //-----------------Long Clikced Listener Starts from here-----------------------------
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listView.setChoiceMode(listView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
                    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
                        ArrayList<String> list_ids = new ArrayList<String>();
                        int count = 0;

                        @Override
                        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                            String data = adapter.getItem(position).getId();
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if (list_ids.contains(data)) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < list_ids.size(); i++) {
                                    // String temp = list_ids.get(i);
                                    if (data == list_ids.get(i)) {
                                        count--;
                                        mode.setTitle(count + " Items Selected");
                                        list_ids.remove(i);
                                        listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg1);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                // listView.getChildAt(pos).setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                                count++;
                                mode.setTitle(count + " Items Selected");
                               listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg2);
                                list_ids.add(data);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                            MenuInflater inflator = mode.getMenuInflater();
                            inflator.inflate(R.menu.menu_delete, menu);
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()){
                                case R.id.action_delete:

                                    for (int i=0; i<list_ids.size(); i++)
                                    {
                                        String temp = list_ids.get(i);
                                        myDb.deleteData(temp);
                                    }
                                    Toast.makeText(ctx, count+" Items Deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    mode.finish();
                                    count = 0;
                                    list_ids.clear();
                                    arrayList.clear();
                                    refreshdata(); //gets data from method and Sets to list View item
                                    //listView.clearChoices();
                                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    //break;
                                default:
                                    return false;
                                //break;
                            }
                            //return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                            editor.putString("checkBox", "false");
                            editor.apply();
                            count = 0;
                            list_ids.clear();
                            arrayList.clear();
                            refreshdata();
                            // listView.clearChoices();
                            listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                           // listView.clearChoices();
                          //  listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        }
                    });   //-----------Lon clik listener ends---------------------------------



            }  //-------------On Create bundel method ends------------------------------------

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
                MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
                SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                        // adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                        //  getPlanets(newText);
                        arrayList.clear();   // MUST CLEAR THE PREVIOUS DATA FROM LIST
                        Cursor cursor = myDb.SearchData(newText);
                        if (cursor != null) {
                            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                do {
                                    Item item = new Item();
                                    item.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                                    item.setName(cursor.getString(1));// gets id fromm database
                                    item.setSurname(cursor.getString(2));  //gets title from database
                                    item.setMarks(cursor.getString(3));
                                    item.setDat(cursor.getString(4));// gets content / body from database
                                 //   item.setCheckBox();
                                    arrayList.add(item);
                                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                            }
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            }

                public void refreshdata(){
                    final Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllData();
                    if(cursor!= null) {
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                            do{
                                Item item = new Item();
                                item.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                                item.setName(cursor.getString(1));// gets id fromm database
                                item.setSurname(cursor.getString(2));  //gets title from database
                                item.setMarks(cursor.getString(3));
                                item.setDat(cursor.getString(4));// gets content / body from database
                                arrayList.add(item);
                            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
                        }
                        adapter = new Adapter(this, R.layout.custom_list_item, arrayList);
                        listView  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }


            }


        /// my log cat 


        12-10 03:48:51.453 6587-6587/com.hexa.adnan.mysqllitedemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        12-10 03:48:51.453 6587-6587/com.hexa.adnan.mysqllitedemo E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
        12-10 03:48:51.453 6587-6587/com.hexa.adnan.mysqllitedemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.hexa.adnan.mysqllitedemo.List_Viwer$2.onItemCheckedStateChanged(List_Viwer.java:101)
        12-10 03:48:51.453 6587-6587/com.hexa.adnan.mysqllitedemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onItemCheckedStateChanged(AbsListView.java:6077)
```

Comment: paste your logcat.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-10 03:42:30.869 863-863/com.hexa.adnan.mysqllitedemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.hexa.adnan.mysqllitedemo.List_Viwer$2.onItemCheckedStateChanged(List_Viwer.java:101)

Comment: list_ids is null..

Comment: thanks for feedback but please can you tell me how i can resolve it... because my all code working fine it only generates error when my list view item more the 15  now when i long clicked for check an item and then selects my 1st item and then if i scroll and selects item no 16 then it generates an error and alos 1st vale check moves to 2nd or 3rd

Comment: I m beginner in Android and also its my 1st question on stack over Flow so please help in detail

Comment: at which line you are getting exception?

Comment: i m trying to change item background color and it also working perfectly.. bt when i scroll my list view then it dosnt working smoothly.. if i checked 1st item and then scroll down and and select 16th item then it crash app or not check 16th item

Comment: listView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg2); on this line in checked state method of long pressed

Comment: can u upload it to github i'll try it.

Comment: ok sure :)  and thankx in advance

Comment: meanwhile go through this http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-delete-multiple-selected-items-listview-tutorial/

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1JZK0Gdq2IJWDhlS0dlZ21iVmM/view?usp=sharing  here is my code